# Restrict deletion of rows in specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple code for deleting rows by selecting specific cell. The problem is that It should not be allowed to delete rows in range `A1:AZ7` I guess I need if statement for this operation? What it should be?

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Unprotect Password:="123456"

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim TestRange As Range

    Set TestRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A1:AZ7")
    Set MyRange = ' slected cell

    If Not Application.Intersect(MyRange, TestRange) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Protect Password:="123456"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am assuming that `"Set MyRange ="` is `ActiveCell`, isn´t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart")
        .Unprotect Password:="123456"

        Dim MyRange     As Range
        Dim TestRange   As Range

        Set TestRange = .Range("A1:AZ7")
        Set MyRange = Selection     ' U Can select many cells

        If Application.Intersect(MyRange.EntireRow.Rows, TestRange.EntireRow.Rows) Is Nothing Then
            'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
            MyRange.EntireRow.Delete
        End If

        .Protect Password:="123456"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Unprotect Password:="123456"

        Dim MyRange As Range
        Dim TestRange As Range

        Set TestRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A1:AZ7")
        Set MyRange = ActiveCell

        If Not Application.Intersect(MyRange, TestRange) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Protect Password:="123456"
    End Sub
```

Comment: But this code will delete one row if the intersection exists!... Not Intersection is Nothing is like "Intersection is something", so it is not according to your question...

Comment: This code is doing what was expected. As my question stated, It should not be allowed to delete rows in range A1:AZ7. You are free to try it yourself. If you select cell in range A1:AZ7 and click button it will not do anything. In all the other cells it will delete one row. You can of course remove Not and Else

Comment: You are right, you are not applying as direct result. Why?

Comment: I just have left some space for `MsgBox ("Please choose the right one")`